# having trouble with setting my footer height and putting space around my social icons

Tags: html, css

please see

`https://forallthetime.com/DEMO/index.html`

would like to adjust my footer height, cant seem to

also, this must be easy, i can not put space betweem my social icons

i tried adjusting my CSS for `grid-container`, `img`, `item4`... no go

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your footer you have a grid container with those declarations:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 5vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "mail num"
    "icons icons";
}
```

You have to play with the min-height and the grid-template-rows. The first 1fr is your first line.

For example:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 4vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 60% 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "mail num"
    "icons icons";
}
```

Play with those 2 values to obtain what you want.

Your social icons are in a tag in the item4 of this grid-container.

Add in your css:

```css
.item4 a {
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

0 top down, 1em left right

play with this value to obtain what you want

Comment: it works! though not in Chrome :( fire fox its flawless and i think its fine on my iphone. Interestingly my laptop edge is fine, on my desktop edge its still as you saw it originaly. what do you suggest?

Comment: hum I don't know! I'm using Chrome and I tested it with Chrome, it was working. So I don't know what. Did you emptied your cache?

Comment: it works! both! i have a lot of empty realestate here. kindly suggest additional footer content, besides a site map. THANKS!!!   do i owe you a $0.25 now?

Comment: pier farrugia, problem resloved :) thanks anyways!

Comment: please see https://forallthetime.com/DEMO/index.html



on small screen, the top image overlaps the hello world divs



can not figure out how to fix that

please help me out!

Comment: another question on my site        please see https://forallthetime.com/DEMO/index.html

on small screen, the top image overlaps the hello world divs

can not figure out how to fix that

need i media query?

please help me out!